# WideNDeep tutorial code

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Concerning this line of code in the [WideNDeep tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py):

```
m.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn(df_train), steps=FLAGS.train_steps)
```

What is the batch_size used for training the deep model?
Presently, it seems to me that the model is not batch_trained? Is there any default batch_size?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `batch_size` as an argument to fit. [See the documentation on `BaseEstimator.fit`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.learn.html#BaseEstimator.fit)

Comment: It does not allow you to pass batch_size as an argument when you have the input_fn.We can use the batch_size only when we give X,Y as input to fit function.

Comment: So the input_fn specifies the batch size.

Comment: How should I change the input_fn(), so that it return batches. Currently, it returns the entire data.

Comment: You can use tf.train.batch: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#batch

Answer (score 0):

I change this tutorial for batch processing as follows:

1. converting the CSV data to TensorFlow format (Example in a TFRecord file); then
2. creating an input_fn from a read_batch function available in tf.contrib.learn (queue)

This is the code I used:

https://gist.github.com/cirocavani/7d9e827102093139acd400b02d2e7afb

The input_fn is like this:

```
def input_fn(mode, data_file, batch_size):
    input_features = create_feature_columns()
    features = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(input_features)

    feature_map = tf.contrib.learn.io.read_batch_record_features(
        file_pattern=[data_file],
        batch_size=batch_size,
        features=features,
        name="read_batch_features_{}".format(mode))

    target = feature_map.pop("label")

    return feature_map, target
```

I think it would have a simpler solution, but I don't know TensorFlow enouth to provide one yet :)